# What patterns are there to handle access/refresh token in SPA SSR?

Tags: single-page-application, server-side-rendering, access-token, refresh-token

I know of the following patterns for token management in server-side rendered SPAs.

*note*: by `frontend server` I mean the server which hosts the SPA and does SSR.

###### Proxying singup/signin/signout/refresh-token requests through frontend server

*Description* All the requests that involves getting tokens in response will be done through frontend server(instead of client making direct ajax request to the backend server). Frontend server exposes only the access token through an endpoint to the client so that it can make other kinds of requests directly to the server.

*Implementation* Frontend server can set the tokens in `httponly` cookies for a stateless implementation. And expose only the access token through an endpoint by calling which the client would be able to get the access token.

*Downside* access token will be compromised in case of an XSS attack.

###### Proxying all the requests to backend API through frontend server

*Description* client makes all the requests to backend through frontend server. No direct request is sent by the client to the backend server.

*Implementation* Frontend server can set the tokens in `httponly` cookies for a stateless implementation.

*Downside* frontend server can become a bottleneck.

Are the solutions which I mentioned correct? Are there anymore downsides to the above-mentioned solutions? Are there any other solution and patterns for token management in SSRed SPAs?

Comment: _"Downside access token will be compromised in case of an XSS attack."_ - Not necessarily: the whole point of using a reverse-proxy for bearer-tokens (and other secrets) is precisely to avoid exposing those values to browser clients. In that situation when you write _"Frontend server exposes only the access token through an endpoint to the client so that it can make other kinds of requests directly to the server."_ - that's just wrong because it defeats the point of keeping secrets a secret.

Comment: _"Implementation Frontend server can set the tokens in httponly cookies for a stateless implementation. "_ - how does using `httponly` cookies make something "stateless"? What do you mean by "stateless" in this context?

Comment: @Dai "that's just wrong because it defeats the point of keeping secrets a secret."
if access token is not exposed to the client, then How can the client make an ajax request 
to a protected endpoint with no access token?

Comment: @Dai What I mean by stateless is that the frontend server does not need to keep track of users tokens in a database or some other kind of storage
(keeping a session data for users somewhere) because the requests (containing cookies) will be self-contained(cookies does not have to be httponly for this to happen), which makes the server easier to scale out

Comment: _" if access token is not exposed to the client, then How can the client make an ajax request to a protected endpoint with no access token?"_ - the `access_token` can be securely encrypted inside a browser-handled (`httponly`) session cookie, and decrypted only by the reverse-proxy server. Even if malicious JS code is able to capture that cookie value it's useless to the attacker because they have no way of decryping it (of course they could still make requests through the reverse-proxy, but only until the session expires).

Comment: @Dai do By "reverse-proxy server" are you referring to the frontend server?

Comment: @Dai Assuming that backend and frontend are on two different domains. Setting httponly cookies from frontend means that the `access_token`
will only be sent to the frontend server, and ajax requests, sent by browser directly to the backend server, neither would have access to the `access_token`
(`access_tokens`) to include it in their requests(as Authorization header) nor would the browser include any httponly cookie in the requests automatically
since the domains are different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252875/discussion-between-gandalf-and-dai).

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding tokens in the browser is often seen as a safer option. eg as described in [OAuth for Browser Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#name-backend-for-frontend-bff-pr). And using the latest strongest cookies instead.

One option for doing so is to issue HTTP only cookies from a sibling domain, eg https://api.example.com, for an SPA at https://www.example.com. This gives you additional deployment options, eg:

- Deploy static content to a content delivery network, for best global web performance
- Deploy the cookie issuing components to an API domain, eg that resolves to a Kubernetes cluster

In cookie terms these domains are in the same site, so cookies are first party and work reliably. The cookies are only ever set via Ajax requests, so the frontend also has good usability control.

This option tends to work best when web and API concerns are strictly separated, eg server rendered content has no secure data. In which case cookies are only needed for API requests.

So not sure if it will suit your architecture, but interesting to know about. It can sometimes be used to enable setups where web developers can completely externalise the security during development.